# Authentication using Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

I searched through the web, but haven't yet found how the whole process works. I want to authenticate users in an application using their Twitter account, then, using this account, to allow then to post information on my server. So I don't want to interact with Twitter anymore, no posting, no reading tweets. I just want to use it as some kind of passport to get users username.

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement some kind of "Login with Twitter" type feature.  You'll still need to send a request to Twitter for user authorization.  Have you looked through the Twitter API?  That's always a good place to start...

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1#102

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.oneall.com/. It allows you to login with most social networks. It has detailed documentation and step by step guides to help you authenticate using a social network.